# Change colour scheme in TextWrangler using applescript?

Tags: applescript, syntax-highlighting, textwrangler

I have a custom colour scheme in TextWrangler that makes code comments the same colour as the background, essentially "hiding" the comments. It can be useful if you just want to focus on your code.

I would like to use an applescript to change TextWrangler's colour scheme so I can map a keyboard shortcut to it and effectively hide and unhide comments with a keyboard shortcut.

The problem is I can't actually see any way to set the colour scheme with TextWrangler's Applescript dictionary. Is there an alternative way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't script the color scheme in TW if it's not in the dictionary.